# Blender 2.9 instantly crashes when I try to render in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, gpu, performance

Blender 2.9 crashes instantly when I try to either render the viewport in cycles or when I try to render the scene in Cycles.
My computer:
Mac Pro early 2009
OSX 10.13.6 High Sierra
3.33ghz 6-core Intel Xeon
48gb ram
Graphics Card:
Nvidia GeForce GTX Titan 
Latest Nvidia drivers

Blender 2.9 doesn't recognize my video card when I pull up preferences. 2.83 works perfectly.

Comment: The crash could be caused by an issue in Embree as report in this [ticket](https://developer.blender.org/T78793). This has already been fixed and will likely be included in the 2.90.1 corrective release.

Comment: The Nvidia GPU not being recognized in 2.90 is expected, since  Nvidia stopped macOS support for the CUDA Toolkit. The last version that was release for it was 10.12. Therefore, Blender 2.90 does not include support for CUDA. This has been announced in the [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Cycles#GPU_Rendering) and is also documented in [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#gpu-rendering). Until Cycles is ported to support the Metal API, this means no GPU rendering on macOS.

Comment: The same happens to me in 2.91, but it also crashes when I try to import/ append/ link files. Does this happen to you?